# Oracle APEX: URL column in interactive grid cannot be edited

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive grid in an APEX application, and one of the columns (header ATTACHMENT) has URLs that open in a new tab. However, as part of the functionality of an interactive grid, I am unable to edit the URL within this column. All the columns are editable, but since I changed this column to a 'Link' the user cannot edit it. I also tried single row view, but same.

Is this possible?
Thanks
[See my interactive grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWr7J.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about specifying the same column (`attachment`) twice? One would be used for editing purposes, and another one as a link. Something like this:

```
select 
  id, 
  attachment                                 edit_url, 
  '<a href="' || attachment ||'">Link</a>'   link_url
from your_table
```

- ID is the primary key column
- EDIT_URL is a usual Text Field
- LINK_URL is a Link column

  - its "Query only" property has to be set to "Yes"
  - "Escape special characters" set to "No"

When you run the page, it'll show 3 columns; EDIT_URL will be editable. Once you modify that column's value and save the changes, LINK_URL will reflect that change and - when you click the "Link" word in that column, it'll lead you to the modified URL.

Comment: Excellent idea! It's a simple solution that did not think about, and was easy to implement. Thanks a lot for your prompt reply!